# How to get the first date in a script

Tags: regex

I have lines of text as follows. I only want the first date after Examination date so that the expected output is 10.08.2017

```
Examination Date 

date:  10.08.2017 
423432

tert
g

534534

Examination Date: 04-07-2017
```

so far I have tried:

```
Examination Date.*?\d{2}.?{2}?.\d{4}
```

but I get the entire result to `04-07-2017`

Comment: Are you coding this in Java? I think you have a different pattern, you missed `\d` in the middle. Actually, you may just capture that part: `Examination Date.*?(\d{2}\W\d{2}\W\d{4})` and grab Group 1 value. Or [`Examination Date:\s*(\d{2}\W\d{2}\W\d{4})\b`](https://regex101.com/r/3tL3eU/1).

Comment: Yes in Java with the DOTALL but I need to keep this on. Also just regexing date.* won't do as the presence of the word date: (rather than Date:) is variable

Comment: Typo in your expected output. Missing `1`?

Comment: Thanks. Corrected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix the pattern by adding `\d` before the `{2}?` and removing unnecessary `?`s abd capture the value you need:

```
String s = "Examination Date \n\ndate:  10.08.2017 \n423432\n\ntert\n\ng\n\n534534\n\nExamination Date: 04-07-2017";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("Examination Date.*?\\b(\\d{2}\\W\\d{2}\\W\\d{4})\\b", Pattern.DOTALL);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
if (matcher.find()){
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1)); // => 10.08.2017
}
```

See the [Java demo](https://ideone.com/RzvvFW) and the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3tL3eU/4). In the code, you only get the first match as `if` is used, not `while`, and the `.` matches line breaks thanks to the `Pattern.DOTALL` modifier.

**Details**

- `Examination Date` - a literal substring
- `.*?` - any 0+ chars, as few as possible
- `\\b` - a word boundary (if you do not care about matching the date as a "whole" word, remove the `\\b`)
- `(\\d{2}\\W\\d{2}\\W\\d{4})` - Group 1:

  - `\\d{2}` - 2 digits
  - `\\W` - any non-word char (punctuation, space, symbol)
  - `\\d{2}\\W` - as above
  - `\\d{4}` - 4 digits
- `\\b` - a trailing word boundary.

Comment: I think the OP wants `10.08.2017 ` as the expected date. The first one.

Comment: @Gurman Well, the pattern remains the same, but `Pattern.DOTALL` is required.